# PHP, Как разрешить запросы только от своего сервера

Tags: php

Как разрешить запрос на API только от своего сервера

Суть такова, что у меня есть API и я хочу разрешить только своему серверу делать туда запросы, в другом случае - запретить достучаться туда

как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: в nginx конфигурации `allow ip; deny all;` ip - ваш сервер

Comment: Зуб даю на отсечение,  тут под "сервером" имеется в виду яваскрипт в браузере

Comment: в запросе ключ/токен, если только это не зуб на отсечение пассатижами выше.